# how to pass a variable function to an onclick event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables

I am a newbie in javascript. I am not sure what am I doing wrong here. I want to pass in a variable which is a function to an onclick event of an anchor tag.I could not figure out. Thanks in advance.

```
    var test = function(val1, val2) { alert("bla"); };  

    $.each( result, function (key, value){ var a = key; var b = key+value; var doSomething = function() { test (a, b)); $('#id').bind("click", test); });
```

I need to create the anchor tags dynamically and pass multiple variables to "onclick" event. so what I am trying to do is create a variable function dynamically inside a for loop and bind it to an anchor tag

Comment: Just write `onclick='test()'` in the string (without concatenation).

Comment: Well, but the way u have written works well. check it here http://jsfiddle.net/VWRq5/ Unnecessarily appending dynamic html for this purpose isnt a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
var test = function() { 
    alert("hello"); 
};  

$("#myUL").append("<li><a href='#' onclick=test()>test</a></li>");
```

Is what you want?

Comment: Thanks Alessandro. Sorry I could not post the question properly due to some errors on the script.

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri - Out of curiosity.The code above given by marcus , works well check here - http://jsfiddle.net/VWRq5/ So why do we need to do as you have given ?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri - den why shud it be done this way ?? Appending html for such purpose isnt required right ? JQuery works fine for this. then what's the need the way you have given ?

Comment: The question it was different, He has change the code into his question, before edit it was an append @bhuvin

Comment: oh .. ! Then too live() or On() events are the way outs right ? Mixing core javascript and JQuery for DOM manipulation isnt a good practice according to me. what say ?

Comment: I'm according with you, I have only answer to the first question and now is change

Comment: sorry guys i could not type my question properly the first time. so most of the stuff wasnt there. it is kinda hard to get used to the stackoverflow rules for posting the question. :)

Comment: I have successfully edited my question now. does anybody have any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $("button").eq(i).on("click", {value: i}, function(event) {
    var msgs = [
      "button = " + $(this).index(),
      "event.data.value = " + event.data.value,
      "i = " + i
    ];
    logDiv.append( msgs.join(", ") + "<br>" );
  });
}
```

jQuery site: [event.data](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/)

Answer (score -2):

You should use :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myUL").click(function(){
         alert("hello");
    });
};
```